# Twilio Call API Integration

Tags: php, twilio

I am a newbie when it comes to Twilio. I would like to Integrate Twilio to a Live Support Site I am building using PHP. Accordingly, if a user to my Site would like to inquire about our products, the user should be able to press a Twilio button and reach us. This is the requirement. A user can Leave a Voicemail, in case the user couldn't get hold of us after a few Attempts. The phone number being used to reach us has to be our normal PSTN/ISDN/PLMN number.

Would you please Let me know in terms of

1. where I have to Start from
2. what APIs I have to call...

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here.

So, There are two things you want to look at, the first is the [Twilio Client How-To](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client), this will allow you to add a button so that the site user makes a call from their browser to your existing PSTN number.

Or, you can add a button that makes a call to the site visitors number and connects them to your existing number. See the [Make and Outbound call page](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request) on Twilio's website. You will also need to take a look at [TwiML](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) for managing the calls.

Depending on which approach works, this is very simple. Create an outbound call to the user's number, and use the URL of some TwiML that connects them to your existing number. Something like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>+xx-your-number-xx</Dial>
</Response>
```

Alternatively, you can use the Client, but you need to add a callerId to the dial attribute.

Comment: All of the prices are listed on the website at http://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing, but note that VOIP is priced separately.

Comment: thanks. In my example, a user to our website calls us by clicking a twilio button. In this case, do you think the user needs to have an account with twilio and have some calling credits? for example, if we try with Skype, a user will be charged by Skype

Comment: No, you would be charged on that to your Twilio account, so it would be free to the site visitor.